# Getting values from View and send it to Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got stuck at this point. Not sure what is going wrong here.

> > Note: I am new to Backbone

**View**

```
var LoginForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template('<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />'+
                        '<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />'+
                         '<input type="button" id="login" value="Login"/>'),
    events: {
        'click #login':'goIn'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    goIn: function() {
            this.model.email = $('#email').val();
    this.model.passowrd = $('#passowrd').val();
        this.model.goIn();
            //this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    }
}); 

var loginForm = new LoginForm({model:loginModel});
loginForm.render();
$('#app').append(loginForm.el);
```

**Model**

```
var LoginFormModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
      defaults: {
            email:"",
            password:""
      },
      goIn: function(req, resp) {
        console.log('hey whats up?'+JSON.stringify(this));
        //this.save();
      }
  });

  var loginModel = new LoginFormModel();
```

I don't anything in the model's `goIn()`. It just prints `{"email":"", "password":""}`.

Comment: Why would that model contain anything? I don't see any `defaults` in it or any `fetch` or `set` calls that would populate it.

Comment: I added `defaults` before but then it printed `"email":"","password":""` so I removed it. Here I am trying to implement a login screen that is why it does not have `fetch` calls.

Comment: So why do you expect `JSON.stringify(this)` to produce something other than `"{}"`? The model is empty so it's JSON form is an empty object.

Comment: Then how can I print values from `View`?

Comment: Read them from things inside the view's `el` (probably using `this.$(...).val()` inside the view) and then `set` them on the model? Backbone doesn't do auto-binding for you.

Comment: I changed as you suggested but no luck. Still same result.

Comment: Have you read the Backbone docs or gone through any tutorials? `model.a = v` and `model.set('a', v)` are entirely different things and only of them is correct. Also, you misspelled "password".

Comment: Right. I was not sure about using the `set`. Fixed it with `this.model.set({"email":this.$('#email').val(), "password":this.$('#password').val()});`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use model.set . In your view, instead of using this.model.email = ..., use :

```
 goIn: function() {
            this.model.set('email', $('#email').val());
            this.model.set('password', $('#passowrd').val());
            this.model.goIn();
            //this.render();
    }
```

This should give you your desired result.